# in vba for excel

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA for excel im trying to make hotkeys to modify cell borders. the hotkey control-shift-Q is supposed to toggle between thick and thin.that part works. i copied and pasted a recorded macro this. that will draw a bottom thin line.

```
With Selection.Borders(xlBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
```

and replaced
`.Weight = xlThin` with  `.Weight = var2`
, that gives me the error
I even tried declaring the variable in the sub, the MSGbox show it right. then I still get an error
any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Public var2 As String
    
    Sub keys()
    
    Dim var2 As String
    var2 = "x1Thin"
    
    Application.OnKey "^+q", "thick"
    Application.OnKey "^+x", "down"
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub down()                       'toggle selected cells to have bottom border or erase
    '
    'Dim var2 As String
    'var2 = "x1Thin"
    MsgBox (var2)
    
    If Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone Then
    'MsgBox ""
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = var2                  '<-----this is what is cant get to work
        End With
        
       
    Else
    
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
    
    End Sub
    
    Sub thick()
    '
    'Dim var2 As String
    'var2 = "x1Thin"
    
    If var2 = "x1Thin" Then
    var2 = "xlMedium"
    Else
    var2 = "x1Thin"
    End If
    MsgBox (var2)
    End Sub
    
    ""
```

Comment: Those (xlThin) etc are enumerations. They represent a number actually. xlThin = 2 for example. In the immediate window `? xlThin` will show the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gokhan writes in the comments, `xlThin` and and `xlMedium` are numbers (the names are there for convenience and better readability).

Declare your variable as number (`Long`). As the variable should live outside your procedure, easiest (although not the cleanest) way is to declare is as global as you already do:

```
Public var2 As Long
```

But remove the declaration in your subroutine `keys`, else you will have 2 variables with the same name, but different scope.

Assing to the variable (be carefull, you have a type in `xlThin`, it's an letter `l`, not the digit `1`:

```
If var2 = xlThin Then
    var2 = xlMedium
Else
    var2 = xlThin
End If
```

Or, shorter:

```
var2 = iif(var2 = xlThin, xlMedium, xlThin)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked ,  I will be more careful with l & 1 and watch for double declarations in the future

Comment: Hi, if your question is answered, mark it as accepted so that others know they don't have to invest more time. Also, it would be good to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how Stackoverflow works